# Keras: better way to implement layer-wise training model?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I'm currently learning implementing layer-wise training model with Keras. My solution is complicated and time-costing, could someone give me some suggestions to do it in a easy way? Also could someone explain the topology of Keras especially the relations among `nodes.outbound_layer`, `nodes.inbound_layer` and how did they associated with tensors: `input_tensors` and `output_tensors`? From the topology [source codes on github](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L87), I'm quite confused about:

`input_tensors[i] == inbound_layers[i].inbound_nodes[node_indices[i]].output_tensors[tensor_indices[i]]`

Why the `inbound_nodes` contain `output_tensors`, I'm not clear about the relations among them....If I wanna remove layers in certain positions of the [`API model`](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), what should I firstly remove? Also, when adding layers to some certain places, what shall I do first?

Here is my solution to a layerwise training model. I can do it on Sequential model and now trying to implement in on the [`API model`](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

To do it, I'm simply add a new layer after finish previous training and re-compile (`model.compile()`) and re-fit (`model.fit()`).

Since Keras model requires output layer, I would always add an output layer. As a result, each time when I wanna add a new layer, I have to remove the output layer then add it back. This can be done using `model.pop()`, in this case `model` has to be a `keras.Sequential()` model.

The `Sequential()` model supports many useful functions including `model.add(layer)`. But for customised model using model API: `model=Model(input=...., output=....)`, those `pop()` or `add()` functions are not supported and implement them takes some time and maybe not convenient.